# Assuming there is no need for frontend rendering or templating engines, what design pattern would you choose? why?

Tags: node.js

Suppose you are to develop an application that is purely composed of RESTful APIs with all CRUD operations done through APIs. Assuming there is no need for frontend rendering or templating engines, what design pattern would you choose & why?